# AxiosError: maxContentLength size of -1 exceeded in VSCode extension development

Tags: axios, vscode-extensions

I want to get token from `https://xxxxx/auth/token` with `post` method. The code of the VS Code plug-in is as follows:

```
// extension.ts
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import axios from 'axios';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    let commandOfGetFileState = vscode.commands.registerCommand('getFileState', uri => { 
        axios(
            {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'https://xxxxx/auth/token',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    // "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
                },
                data: {
                    data: {
                        "type": "JWT-Token",
                        "attributes": {
                            "project": "xxxxx",
                            "secret": "xxxxx",
                            "account": "xxxxx",
                            "enterprise": "xxxxx",
                        }
                    },
                },
                maxContentLength: Infinity,
                maxBodyLength: Infinity,
            }
        )
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('----- err: ', err);
      });
    }); 

    context.subscriptions.push(commandOfGetFileState);
}
```

When I debug the plug-in, I encountered the following error:
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GylKs.png)

But,when I run the same code in NodeJS,It's OK:

```
const axios = require('axios');

export class MyFactory {
  async getAigcToken() {
    axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://xxxxx/auth/token',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      data: {
        data: {
          "type": "JWT-Token",
          "attributes": {
            "project": "xxxxx",
            "secret": "xxxxx",
            "account": "xxxxx",
            "enterprise": "xxxxx",
          }
        },
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.log('success res: ', res);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('failed: ', err.response.data);
      });
  }
```

I don't know what the problem is.

As described above, I run the same code in NodeJS, it's OK